# How to filter a specific column character in R after importing data with fread function

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have imported in r a .tsv file with fread function from data.table package

```
dt <- fread( "full_data.tsv", nrows = 1000000)
```

the dataset have 37 columns, something like this:

| ID | DATA | lan | geo_coord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10002 | 2020-02-01 | eng | [10.2,32.5] |
| 10003 | 2020-02-01 | eng | [12.2,42.5] |
| 10004 | 2020-02-01 | eng | [14.4,22.6] |
| 10005 |  | eng | [32.6,23.5] |
| 10004 | 2020-02-01 | eng | [16.2,21.2] |
| 10006 |  | eng | [16.7,20.2] |
| 10007 | 2020-02-01 | eng |  |
| 10008 | 2020-02-01 | eng |  |
| 10009 | 2020-02-01 | eng |  |

I would filter only geo-coord column (character) in order to remove empty cells obtaining a result like this:

| ID | DATA | lan | geo_coord |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10002 | 2020-02-01 | eng | [10.2,32.5] |
| 10003 | 2020-02-01 | eng | [12.2,42.5] |
| 10004 | 2020-02-01 | eng | [14.4,22.6] |
| 10005 |  | eng | [32.6,23.5] |
| 10004 | 2020-02-01 | eng | [16.2,21.2] |
| 10006 |  | eng | [16.7,20.2] |

I tried with filter from dplyr without result.

Comment: `I tried with filter from dplyr without result` What was the code that you used?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example using `dput` with selected columns so that it is clear whether you have `NA` values or empty strings ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>%
  filter(geo_coord != "" & !is.na(geo_coord))
```

It seems the missing are not coded as such, but are empty strings.

Comment: Hi Akrun, I tried your code on another dataset and it works, unfortunately it doesn't work on the dataset I need, but I think I didn't give you correct details about it.  If you're curious you can find it on this website: https://crisisnlp.qcri.org/tbcov , in the second window "Country release:" I choosed "Italy (2gb)". on the same page there are also metadata, the correct column name is "geo_coordinates_lat_lon" instead of "geo_coord" as I wrote in the post.  Actually I had problems to import this dataset in R because It was too large, so I thought to solve applying a rough strategy:

Comment: Import few millions of rows at a time and then filtering data according to  "geo_coordinates_lat_lon" values  as I need only rows that present a value in this column

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    filter(complete.cases(na_if(geo_coord, "")))
```